# IIS Document access via asp.net site outside of user session

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, webforms, .net-4.7.2

We have a site that has temporary folder in the site itself. Which is required by 3rd party tools.
`https://server/site/tempfiles/`. We've denied access to it via `web.config` file. If someone browses to this folder via URL, access is denied.
This site is protected by Forms Auth. But not all scenarios work as expected.

**Scenario 1**
The IIS authentication set `Anonymous Authentication = Enabled` on this `tempfiles` folder. The folder is not browseable via URL. When temp document (PDF) is created for viewing in the page document viewer, this document is available to direct access via URL. For example `https://server/site/tempfiles/mydoc.pdf`.

**But in this case anyone who has this URL can also access this file**

**Scenario 2**
The IIS authentication set `Anonymous Authentication = Disabled` on this `tempfiles` folder. The folder is not browseable via URL. When temp document (PDF) is created for viewing in the page document viewer, this document is **not available to access** via URL directly. For example `https://server/site/tempfiles/mydoc.pdf`. **The problem** however, is that this document is also not available to view when user clicks on a link in the page, which should open this document in the new browser popup window. HTTP 401. (Works with `Anonymous Authentication = true`)

Ideally, the goal here is to have this document not accessible via direct URL by anyone but the original requestor, person with session. And popup should work.

Thank you

Comment: Simply enable forms authentication on the entire application, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/building-and-running-aspnet-applications/how-to-take-advantage-of-the-iis-integrated-pipeline#enabling-forms-authentication-for-the-entire-application Then your settings in `web.config` takes effect on all files, not just ASP.NET contents.

Comment: @LexLi The forms auth is enabled. It says in the question *"This site is protected by Forms Auth"*

Comment: Are users required to logon to the site? If yes, then secure that folder by a user role. If users are not required, then I'll post a answer below as to how to do this.

Comment: @LexLi Yes. Our Users are logged on and there is session with expiration. We have a cookie. This is a sticky session environment. The only other thing that has been added is `<location path="TempFiles"><system.web><authorization><deny users="*" /><allow users="poolUser" /></authorization></system.web>`. A very interesting behavior regarding Anonymous Authentication. We usually have Anonymous Authentication and Forms Authentication enabled. But now this behavior is discovered. Especially that popup window seems has no access to this document. While main window has.

Comment: "Enabling ASP.NET forms authentication" and "enabling ASP.NET forms authentication on all contents" are different things, and the later is only possible on integrated pipeline mode and requires extra configuration as that article indicated. So I wonder what your statement of "This site is protected by Forms Auth", as if you merely toggled the flag to enable forms authentication but missed the steps to enable it for all contents, the behaviors you observed/described above are then by design.

Comment: @LexLi Sure, it is protected. If you not logged-in, there is no way for you to go through global.aspx. We have the membership an all 9 yards. If your cookie expires, you will be thrown out. I must read closer the link you've sent....

Comment: Your description became more ambiguous to me, so there isn't much to comment further. You might try FRT and ASP.NET ETW as they might reveal more internals to you. But if you want any other to help, then likely access to this server is required.